# Retrieve number of members of a Facebook group on a certain date

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

Does anyone know if there is a way to retrieve the number of members a FB Group had on a certain date?

The usecase is that I want to make a historical graph of member-growth.

A hack could be to check when current members joined, but then you'd miss all members that have joined and left.

Comment: have you tried a cronjob ? if its possible to get the number of members with a script, the cronjob will do the rest. If you want to track users from the past I guess its not possible to get this data from FB graph api

Comment: Yeah, once we decide to start measuring, but I'd like to analyse community activity in the past as well; but we'll probably have to use a proxy value of some sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading some [other discussions](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200373775089515), it seems like there is no Insight data available for groups, only registered domains, pages and page posts. You won't be able to access historic data directly. You can start measuring now and build up your graph of membership growth by accessing the [group/members](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/group/members/) API regularly (You can use cron to do this in a lightweight way and add the data to your database).

Answer (score -1):

Not so sure with Facebook groups, but with the Facebook App, you can record the access token of the users for later use. Or you can store member id and date they joined in your database. Heroku provide Postgres for that. For the free cronjob, you can use like setCronjob.com to regularly schedule the offline jobs like gathering and calculating the statistic based on the user data that you stored.